# Docker Bitnami/WordPress keeps deleting the /wp-config.php and /wp-contents from mounted volume

Tags: docker, bitnami

(1) Spent the last 18 hours trying to get Docker Bitnami/WordPress (on Windows 10) working in some usable way and still haven't been able to get a suitable environment for development.

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: bitnami/wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
      - "443:8443"
      - "22:2222"
    environment:
      - "WORDPRESS_SKIP_BOOTSTRAP=yes"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_HOST=mariadb"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PORT_NUMBER=3306"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=<user>"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_PASSWORD=<pswd>"
      - "WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=<dbname>"
      - "WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/wp_bitnami:/opt/bitnami/wordpress
      # - "wordpress_data:/opt/bitnami/wordpress"
      # - "wordpress_symlink:/bitnami/wordpress"
      - ./volumes/conf/wp-cron:/etc/cron.d/wp-cron  # Cron task
      - ./volumes/conf/ssh/ida_rsa.pub:/home/bitnami/.ssh/authorized_keys   # SSH *.pub
      - ./volumes/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf:ro   # .htaccess
      - ./volumes/conf/vhosts/vhost.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf:ro   # http:80
      - ./volumes/conf/vhosts/https-vhost.conf:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-https-vhost.conf:ro   # https:443
      - ./volumes/conf/certs/server.crt:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/server.crt:ro  # SSL *.crt
      - ./volumes/conf/certs/server.key:/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/server.key:ro   # SSL *.key
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    environment:
      - "ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes"
      - "MARIADB_ROOT_USER=root"
      - "MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=<pswd>"
      - "MARIADB_USER=<user>"
      - "MARIADB_PASSWORD=<pswd>"
      - "MARIADB_DATABASE=<dbname>"
      - "MARIADB_CHARACTER_SET=utf8mb4"
      - "MARIADB_COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"
      - "MARIADB_SKIP_TEST_DB=yes"
      - "MARIADB_ENABLE_SLOW_QUERY=1"
      - "MARIADB_LONG_QUERY_TIME=5"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"  # Expose MariaDB on port 3306
    volumes:
      - ./init/mysql/db_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-startdb.d/db_dump.sql
      - "mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb"
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

  memcached:
    image: bitnami/memcached:latest
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    environment:
      - MEMCACHED_CACHE_SIZE=512 
    networks:
      - wordpress_network

networks:
  wordpress_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  wordpress_symlink:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./volumes/wordpress-symlink
  wordpress_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./volumes/wordpress
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ./volumes/mariadb
```

In this configuration, I boot with volume mounted to my root WordPress folder (which has all files including `/wp-content`, `/wp-config.php`, `.htaccess`).

After the server boots, Bitnami removes my files from `./volume/wp_bitnami` and moves them to `/bitnami/wordpress`. But in doing so, the files disappear from my host machine, and are now lost and irrecoverable.

So then I tried to mount to `./bitnami/wordpress` so I could persist those files too, using this configuration:

```
    volumes:
      #- ./volumes/wp_bitnami:/opt/bitnami/wordpress
      - "wordpress_data:/opt/bitnami/wordpress"
      - "wordpress_symlink:/bitnami/wordpress"
```

In this configuration, the server crashes immediately after boot, and refuses to initialize.

So if I try to persist my `/wp-content` and `/wp-config.php` files, so that they're not lost, the server refuses to initialize at all.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Initially I suspected it could be a Windows Permissions issue. But `Bitnami/Mariadb` is mounted without issues and can manage own files bidirectionally, so it looks like an issue with something `Bitnami/WordPress` is doing that causes the server to crash.

Help is appreciated.

At my wits here with how much time I wasted on this.

(2) Also, when I use dockerfiles they do not seem to ever be run, ie:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Something simple like:

```
# Use the Bitnami WordPress image as the base image
FROM bitnami/wordpress:latest

# Add the custom cron job to the crontab
COPY ./init/cron/custom-cron /etc/cron.d/custom-cron
```

Dockerfile is NEVER being run when running `docker-compose up -d`. Is this a Windows 10 issue? I've spent hours Googling and asking ChatGPT and nothing has helped. I ended up mounting all the files I need to copy using `volume:` instead because it's the only thing that worked.

Comment: Why are you using `/opt`? The [docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress/) say to use `--volume wordpress_data:/bitnami/wordpress`

Comment: @Phil ah, interesting observation, I guess I don't actually need to back-up `/opt/bitnami/wordpress`. I disabled that volume and now it's working. What about `.htaccess`, I have custom code in there for redirects and cache, how do I back-up `.htaccess` and also allow WordPress to write to it as needed? Because when I boot, Bitnami/Wordpress try to overwrite the wordpress-htaccess file in vhosts, I had to put `:ro` flag. Or am I complicating things again 